# Downcasting with instanceof Operator

Tags: java

Downcasting is when child class refers to the object of Parent class. I tried doing it without the instanceof operator.

```
class Food { }  
class bread4 extends Food {  
  static void method(Food a) {  
       bread4 b=(bread4)a;
       System.out.println("ok downcasting performed");  
  }  
   public static void main (String [] args) {  
    Food a=new bread4();  
    bread4.method(a);  
  }  
}
```

Can anyone help me in this by using instanceof operator?

Comment: You can't do the actual cast with `instanceof`. It simply checks if an instance is of a specific type. You still have to do the cast.

Answer (score 3):

**instanceof** operator provides runtime type checking. For instance, if you had a class Food and two subtypes, Bread4 and Bread5, then:

```
static void method(Food a) {
   Bread4 b = (Bread4) a;
   System.out.println("Downcasting performed"); 
}
```

calling this method like:

```
Food four = new Bread4();
Food five = new Bread5();
Bread4.method(four); //the cast inside is done to Bread4, therefore this would work
Bread4.method(five); //the object of type Bread5 will be cast to Bread4 -> ClassCastException
```

To avoid this, you use the **instanceof** operator

```
static void method(Food a) {
   if (a instanceof Bread4) {
       Bread4 b = (Bread4) a;
       System.out.println("Downcasting performed"); 
   }
}
```

therefore, in case you call

```
Bread4.method(five)
```

the check return false so no ClassCastException occurs.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
static void method(Food a) {
    if (a instanceof bread4) {
        bread4 b = (bread4) a;
        System.out.println("Downcasting performed");
    }
}
```

The `instanceof` operator takes an object on the left hand side and checks if it is an instance of the right hand side argument which is a class.

```
obj instanceof Claz
```

This returns `true` if the class of `obj` is an instance of `Claz`.

On a side note, I also do highly recommend that you follow Java naming conventions. Instead of naming your class `bread4`, name it `Bread4`.

Classes should start with upper case letters whereas variables and methods should start with lower case letters.